# How can I display image in eclipse?

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, image, imageicon

Need Help , I'm using eclipse on linux ,I have a code java MineSweeper Game when I run it
[image]

the images in the matrix are not displayed even there is no error in code ,& the same code run perfectly in another machine 
[image]

th images is in folder

[image]

& called in the code

[image]

I tried to run it with intellij the same result no image

Comment: 1) Post code in the forum, not an image of the code. 2) Use ImageIO to read your images. You will get an error message if there is a problem reading the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `Drapeau.PNG` in your screenshot. So that could be the problem. **But more likely, the problem is that your filenames seem to actually end in `.png`, not `.PNG`. Linux filesystems are case-sensitive.**